# MView problem after dropping it

Tags: oracle, jobs, materialized-views, ora-00600

i,

I have one Materialized view on one server which is created by DB link .
There is one job running on that Mview.(craeted with dbms_refresh.make earlier).

Now I have craeted 3 new fields in original table.

there was job running on the Mview, I dropped the job by DBMS_refresh.destroy.
Then dropped the Mview ( i forgot to drop Indexes on view)

Now when i am trying to create the Mview with SQL which i sxtracted before,
It is giving error as :-

Error starting at line 1 in command:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW TTMU_LAVORAZIONE_TT
  TABLESPACE "TTSTAT_DATA"
  LOGGING 
  PCTFREE 10
  PCTUSED 40
  INITRANS 1
  MAXTRANS 255
  STORAGE
  (
    INITIAL 5M
    NEXT 5M
    MINEXTENTS 1
    MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
    PCTINCREASE 0
    FREELISTS 1
    FREELIST GROUPS 1
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
  )
NOCACHE NOPARALLEL BUILD IMMEDIATE
USING INDEX
REFRESH ON DEMAND FAST 
WITH ROWID 
DISABLE QUERY REWRITE  AS
SELECT T288.C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8,C536870915,C536870916,C536870917,
       C536870918,C536870919,C536870920,C536870921,C536870922,C536870927,
       C536870928,C536870929,C536870930,C536870931,C536870932,C536870933,
       C536870937,C536870939,C536870940,C536870941,C536870942,C536870945,
       C536870951,C536870952,C536870953,C536870954,C536870955,C536870956,
       C536870957,C536870959,C536870961,C536870962,C536870965,C536871100
  FROM T288@STAT2TTM.WORLD
```

Error at Command Line:1 Column:0
Error report:

```
SQL Error: ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [17113], [0x000000000],
                      [], [], [], [], [], []
00600. 00000 -  "internal error code, arguments: [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s],
                [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s]"
*Cause:    This is the generic internal error number for Oracle program
           exceptions. This indicates that a process has encountered an
           exceptional condition.
*Action:   Report as a bug - the first argument is the internal error number
```

Error starting at line 26 in command:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX I_SNAP$_TTMU_LAVORAZIONE_T 
  ON TTMU_LAVORAZIONE_TT (M_ROW$$ ASC)
  TABLESPACE "TTSTAT_DATA"
  LOGGING 
  PCTFREE 10
  INITRANS 2
  MAXTRANS 255
  STORAGE
  (
    INITIAL 5M
    NEXT 5M
    MINEXTENTS 1
    MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
    PCTINCREASE 0
    FREELISTS 1
    FREELIST GROUPS 1
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
  )
```

Error at Command Line:26 Column:0
Error report:
SQL Error: Closed Connection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the action is pretty clear:

> *Action:   Report as a bug - the first argument is the internal error number

This is an internal error. Follow instructions from Note [ID 153788.1] *Troubleshoot an ORA-600 or ORA-7445 Error Using the Error Lookup Tool* on [Oracle support site](http://support.oracle.com).

Answer (score 0):

You must:
- drop the snapshot/mview
- drop the snapshot log on the master table
- create a new snapshot log on the master table
- recreate your mview and simplify your create statement to the following:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW TTMU_LAVORAZIONE_TT
  TABLESPACE "TTSTAT_DATA"
REFRESH FAST START WITH SYSDATE NEXT SYSDATE + 5/1440
WITH ROWID 
AS
SELECT T288.C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8,C536870915,C536870916,C536870917,
       C536870918,C536870919,C536870920,C536870921,C536870922,C536870927,
       C536870928,C536870929,C536870930,C536870931,C536870932,C536870933,
       C536870937,C536870939,C536870940,C536870941,C536870942,C536870945,
       C536870951,C536870952,C536870953,C536870954,C536870955,C536870956,
       C536870957,C536870959,C536870961,C536870962,C536870965,C536871100
  FROM T288@STAT2TTM.WORLD;
```

The above will add a refresh dbms_job that brings the table up-to-date every 5 minutes.  You can change it to meet your requirements.

After you create it you must run:

```
exec dbms_snapshot.refresh("TTMU_LAVORAZIONE_TT",'C');
exec dbms_snapshot.refresh("TTMU_LAVORAZIONE_TT",'F');
```

That should take care of it.  You will need to use an alternate method if the table is massive.  I don't know the size so i'm assuming not too big.

Answer (score 0):

Check the alert log for the database for clues as to what may be happening in your database. That will likely point you at one or more trace files where more information on the problem can be found. Sometimes you can resolve the problem on your own.